# IP forwarding from one interface to another on Debian 7

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, hostapd

**Background**

The Debian 7 that I run has the following interfaces

```
wlan3 == Internet connection  85.5.48.64/24
wlan2 == act as an AP (hostapd) 192.168.5.1/24
```

I run the following settings on the terminal

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
```

**Problem**

But, `wlan2` interface cannot access to the Internet.

```
root@arm:/etc# ping -I wlan2 google.com
PING google.com (173.194.34.78) from 192.168.5.1 wlan2: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how I can solve it?

**Related settings and outputs**

```
root@arm:/etc# uname -a
Linux arm 3.14.4-armv7-x6 #1 SMP Tue May 20 15:29:16 CEST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 0
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/rp_filter: No such file or directory
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# ip route
default via 85.5.48.1 dev wlan3 
85.5.48.0/24 dev wlan3  proto kernel  scope link  src 85.5.48.110 
192.168.5.0/24 dev wlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.1
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         supercore.backb 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan3
85.5.48.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan3
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

---

```
 root@arm:/etc# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    network 192.168.5.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan3
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Wed Jun  4 08:39:05 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2634:425297]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1992:263181]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:488]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:84]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  4 08:39:05 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Wed Jun  4 08:39:05 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4705:642335]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [31:4015]
-A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  4 08:39:05 2014
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# ifconfig 
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:42:30:df:a0:d0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::4042:30ff:fedf:86d0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:31581 (30.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:560 (560.0 B)  TX bytes:560 (560.0 B)

mon.wlan2 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 64-01-02-18-03-6B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24415 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5163458 (4.9 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:02:47:a8:24:80  
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:166955 (163.0 KiB)  TX bytes:230200 (224.8 KiB)

wlan3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:02:47:14:18:be  
          inet addr:85.5.64.110  Bcast:85.5.64.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5549564 (5.2 MiB)  TX bytes:27413 (26.7 KiB)
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# cat /etc/hostapd.conf 
interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=test_network
hw_mode=g
channel=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf 
option domain-name "mydomain.org";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.5.10 192.168.5.20;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.5.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.5.1;
  option routers 192.168.5.1;
option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4;
}
```

---

```
root@arm:/etc# hostapd -v
hostapd v2.2-devel
```

---

Wi-Fi devices use `AR9271` chipset and `ath9k_htc` driver

**EDIT:**

```
root@arm:~#  tcpdump -i wlan2 -n icmp
[  569.446472] device wlan2 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:54:31.260589 IP 192.168.5.10 > 83.5.146.49: ICMP echo request, id 3867, seq 17, length 64
16:55:54.175933 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 1, length 64
16:55:55.185028 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 2, length 64
16:55:56.192626 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 3, length 64
16:55:57.200836 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 4, length 64
16:55:58.208679 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 5, length 64
16:55:59.216827 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 6, length 64
16:56:00.224792 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 7, length 64
16:56:01.232757 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 8, length 64
16:56:02.241485 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 9, length 64
16:56:03.249084 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 10, length 64
16:56:04.256561 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 11, length 64
16:56:05.264404 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 12, length 64
16:56:06.272613 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 13, length 64
16:56:07.281494 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 14, length 64
16:56:08.288482 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 15, length 64
16:56:09.296661 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 16, length 64
16:56:10.304534 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 17, length 64
^C
18 packets captured
18 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped[  687.418762] device wlan2 left promiscuous mode
 by kernel
root@arm:~#  tcpdump -i wlan3 -n icmp
[  699.226867] device wlan3 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:56:22.402374 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 29, length 64
16:56:23.408142 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 30, length 64
16:56:24.416259 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 31, length 64
16:56:25.424743 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 32, length 64
16:56:26.435974 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 33, length 64
16:56:27.439971 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 34, length 64
16:56:28.448028 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 35, length 64
16:56:29.456024 IP 192.168.5.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3945, seq 36, length 64
^C
8 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped [  706.608520] device wlan3 left promiscuous mode
by kernel
root@arm:~#
```

Comment: In the first snippet, the names of the interfaces are reversed.  Consider fixing this (I don't possess enough karma to do this minor edit myself).

Comment: So, what was the fix?

Comment: I meant the first snippet in the question. The connection problem still remains

Comment: I notice you have a bridge interface there. What's it doing there?

Comment: it was created by hostapd previously. I removed it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Leave the bridge created by hostapd in place. Then connect to this access point from anything (cellular phone, laptop, desktop), and issue the following ping command: ping -c3 8.8.8.8  . Can you tell me what the output is?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but two hints not fit for the comment format:

- When you `ping` like this, the packet does not traverse the `FORWARD` chain and it goes right through the `OUTPUT` chain, so you're not really testing the firewall setup FWIW.

  Another problem which might occur due to the same reason (though I'm not really sure) is that since the packet is generated on the local host, not *forwarded,* masquerading won't apply to it and so it will supposedly be killed by the kernel at the moment the stack would send it through `wlan3`—because for that network the packet having its source address in a private subnet would be "martian", and [sending such packets is explicitly prohibited for routers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812#section-5.3.7).  Anyway, even if this packet would be sent, it would be killed by the `85.5.48.1` gateway for the same reason.

  To prove or disprove this hypothesis, use `tcpdump` on the outgoing interface:

  1. Run

     ```
      # tcpdump -i wlan3 -n icmp
     ```
  2. Ping as before and see if you'll see any ICMP echo requests on the wire, and if yes, which addresses they contain in their IP headers.
- Your firewall setup has the policy for its `FORWARD` chain set to `ACCEPT`.  If this is OK for your setup, there's no sense to add explicit rules to that chain since everything is allowed anyway.

  On the other hand, you might consider setting that policy to `DROP`.  Most setups have policies for `INPUT` and `FORWARD` set to `DROP` and then allow only explicit kinds of traffic.

  But note that in your case having no rules (with `ACCEPT` policies) is just okay while you're getting your forwarding working.  After that, consider tightening the setup.

Comment: thank you for the reply and information. I appended the tcpdump outputs as an EDIT on the question. I ping 8.8.8.8 from a different computer that is connected to the wlan2 interface (hostapd), but I did not get any reply. I cannot web-browse neither. Do you think it is the access point (router that debian is connected) that kills the IP forwarding or have any new suggestion?

Comment: The tcpdump on interface wlan3 indicates that the kernel is forwarding the ICMP echo requests, but not translating them.  The expected output on wlan3 would be 85.5.64.110 -> 8.8.8.8.  The behaviour here is no different than simply just turning on IP forwardin with sysctl.  (perhaps that is the problem..?)

Comment: If you could, show a tcpdump with -v to display the packet's TTL counters.  This may give insight.

Comment: @NevinWilliams, I powered the device today and here is the settings http://pastebin.com/eB7G3XRT (same as above). Here is the tcpdump outputs http://pastebin.com/W0QfxqHD I ping to 192.168.5.1 then 8.8.8.8 from another computer (192.168.5.10). This time, wlan3 does not show icmp at all. I don't know what is different this time. As an extra thing, here is the .config file of the Kernel http://paste.ubuntu.com/7520069/

Answer (score 0):

I would start by erasing both of your FORWARD table rules

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o wlan2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan2 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
```

just keep the simple NAT rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now lets get the thing working; after that we can think of probably better rules for protecting wlan3 net

Comment: Thanks Pat, I defined the table as you suggested but it does not solve the problem

Comment: are you adding that rule to a completely "open" iptables module? I mean; are you sure there are not previous rules preventing normal routing within your box?

Comment: I verify that on the boot iptables-save shows a clean table http://pastebin.com/9ZZDDUYt then I add the new rule.

Comment: then it looks like your box is not routing among its interfaces. do you have IP forwarding enabled? you sure /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1 when you perform your tests?

Comment: sysctl -p shows the same output that is posted in the question. it shows ip forwarding is enabled. do you know what could cause to block IP forwarding or how can I debug it?

Comment: at the moment forget about NAT; from wlan2 try pinging 85.5.48.64 that has to work if routing works. I have also seen some weird bridge interface "br0"  and also "mon.wlan2" check that out.

Comment: they were created by hostapd. I removed the bridge interface br0, mon.wlan2 is the monitoring interface for the AP.

Comment: get the simplest possible system with the 2 interfaces and verify the routing works; that's the first step.

Comment: I forgot to write about it. wlan2 does not ping the wlan3's IP addr.

Comment: Just in case, sysctl -p shows the same output as it is posted in the question

Comment: verify iptables is fully open; you have to make that ping among interfaces to work; it has to be some simple thing you are overlooking or you are getting wrong info.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to miss something in problems like this, but this is what caught my eye:

In **/etc/network/interfaces**, you haven't defined a default gateway for `wlan2`. The default gateway for `wlan2` should be the same as the IP address itself, since the forwarding box will be the router.

```
auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    network 192.168.5.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.5.1
```

EDIT: I just noticed that `wlan3` doesn't have a gateway either in the output of `ip route`. Missed that earlier. `wlan3` must also be configured with a gateway, either through DHCP or manually. This gateway will be the router for that network, which is not the box we're talking about here.

Can you check if the following works?

```
ping -I wlan3 google.com
```

If it doesn't, your box is not configured correctly for accessing the internet, and consequently NAT is not going to work either.

Comment: Thanks Yørn. I added the gateway line on /etc/network/interfaces, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I missed that `wlan3` doesn't have a gateway either, taken from the output of `ip route`. I added this info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you show there are no problems, given that the Internet is connected to `wlan3` is is expected that

```
ping -I wlan2 google.com
```

will not work, depending on the version of ping `-I` either means send the packet out of a particular interface, or use the interfaces address as the source address.